# How to login with AWS CLI using credentials profiles

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, command-line-interface, aws-cli, amazon-ecr

I want to setup multiple AWS profiles so that I can easily change settings and credentials when jumping between projects.

I've read the AWS documentation but it's quite vague about how to select what profile you want to use when logging in.

When I'm trying to login it's just giving me this error which seems to indicate that it's not picking up any credentials.

`An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.`

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To setup multiple profiles for AWS login you need to the following:

1. Setup the credentials file with your access keys
2. Setup default settings for profiles (optional)
3. Set the AWS_PROFILE environment variable
4. Remove previous AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

**1: ~/.aws/credentials**

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id =
aws_secret_access_key =

[cat]
aws_access_key_id = XXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXX

[dog]
aws_access_key_id = XXXX
aws_secret_access_key = XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**2: ~/.aws/config**

```
[default]
region = eu-central-1

[profile cat]
region = us-west-2

[profile dog]
region = ap-northeast-1
```

**3. Select profile**

The selected profile is determined by the `$AWS_PROFILE` environment variable. In bash this could be done in `~\.bash_profile` by adding a line `export AWS_PROFILE="cat"`. To switch profiles in the current terminal, type `AWS_PROFILE=dog`.

**4. Remove global settings**

You also need to make sure that the environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` **are not set** because the aws-cli will give priority to those variables over profiles.

**Running**

You can then login to the AWS service of your choice. To see what profile is currently in use `echo $AWS_PROFILE`. Example command for ECR login would be `$(aws ecr get-login)`

**Debugging**

If you're still having problems you can add the `--debug` flag to see what credentials it's using for the command.

Comment: Great answer! You can also override the profile on a CLI command with `--profile <name>`.

Answer (score 1):

For me although I setup everything is above, I have older aws cli version is causing this issue.

```
$ curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip" -o "awscli-bundle.zip"
$ unzip awscli-bundle.zip
$ sudo ./awscli-bundle/install -i /usr/local/aws -b /usr/local/bin/aws
```

By applying above commands it resolves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

After a couple of minutes, I found the rule :

> If you want to use `AWS_PROFILE` makes sure that the rest of AWS env vars are unset (NOT **empty** only ... MUST be **UNSET**).

```
profile=$AWS_PROFILE
unset $(printenv |grep AWS_ | cut -f1 -d"=");
export AWS_PROFILE=${profile};
```

Then :

```
  # with aws cli >= 1.x
  $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ${aws_region})

  # with aws cli >= 2.x
  registry=${aws_account_id}.dkr.ecr.${aws_region}.amazonaws.com
  aws ecr get-login-password --region ${aws_region} | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin ${registry}
```