# specify role while uploading file to s3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a profile `clientProject` setup in my aws config file. I also have the necessary credentials in my aws credentials file. However, if I create a Python script from scratch:

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('catalog.json', 'testunzipping','catalog.json')
```

I am unable to run it because before uploading the file, I would need to switch/assume roles on AWS so that I can have the necessary permissions.

```
boto3.exceptions.S3UploadFailedError: Failed to upload catalog.json to testunzipping/catalog.json: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: Access Denied
```

How can I specify the profile and existing role using an isolated script?

Comment: How are you running the script?

Comment: You can set that profile as default profile and then run the script via the cli.

Comment: i am running on the terminal ```python filename.py```. Any other ways, except setting it as the default profile? @DevangSanghani

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44243368/how-to-login-with-aws-cli-using-credentials-profiles#:~:text=To%20switch%20profiles%20in%20the%20current%20terminal%2C%20type%20AWS_PROFILE%3Ddog%20.&text=You%20also%20need%20to%20make,to%20those%20variables%20over%20profiles.

Answer (score 1):

As per boto3 documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#shared-credentials-file), you cloud use the following to use your `clientProject` profile.

```
session = boto3.Session(profile_name='clientProject')
s3 = session.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file('catalog.json', 'testunzipping','catalog.json')
```